# Changing primary key in SQL table

Tags: sql

I am creating a device Management System, where all devices such as mobile phones, PDA, Computers etc. are linked to "owners".

Setting up the tbldevice I found that I do not get IMEI-numbers from all devices, some just Show Serial numbers, some do not even have These.

As I insert into the table also devices which are already in use, I do not have the packaging, where usually a Serial number can be found.

But I want to use EITHER Serial number OR IMEI as PK to avoid duplicates. Right now I have two fields for s/n and IMEI. I cannot make a combined PK, due to above reason.

Any idea how I should set up a proper PK?

Comment: Autogenerated ID is handy. Combine with unique constraints.

Comment: Autogenerated ID is already in use. The combination of s/n plus IMEI, even if one of them have NULL values seem to solve my Problem. To a later stage it is unlikely that a user retrieves the missing value, either s/n or IMEI, because otherwise there would not be a Violation of the unique key. Thx yr reply. Michael

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Do you realise that there are cases where you know *both* the imei and the serialnumber? Do you know there are cases where you know *neither* ? (because you don't know them *yet*, or because they are under investigation)

Comment: @joop: because the device does not Show either! Cheaper devices might not have a Serial number somewhere outside.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add column filled with

```
nvl(SN,'##SN##') || nvl(IMEI,'#IMEI#')
```

and some logic to fill it when update/insert table. If they are numeric maybe it is possible to replace missing number with some unused numbers like

```
nvl(SN,9999999999) || nvl(IMEI,9999999999)
```

Create primary key on the column.

Comment: As he said, there may be phones with SN but no IMEI, and IMEI but no SN. If someone added the phone again but with both, this solution would not work.

Comment: You're right if someone will insert the same device second time it won't work. Only ide is about putting two unique indexes to not allow insert duplicates and handle them separately but this can be not acceptable due to performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have nor IMEI nor serial number can't recognize the phone/pda, then you need IMEI and/or serial number, and both must be uniques.

And can combine IMEI and serial number to do a single primary key, with a trick: if don't have IMEI fill in with a unique value that don't conflict with existing IMEI values, like unique number, or concatenating random and timestamp; and same behaviour for the serial number.

Then IMEI and serial number don't have null values neither duplicates and you can do your combined primary key.

Comment: this would not prevent from duplicates! The second time you want to insert the same device, again you have just either s/n or IMEI, but with any random number it does not prevent from inserting. Michael

Comment: Of course, you need some logic to verify if some IMEI and/or serial number is already registered (can make an unique index for IMEI and other for serial number). I only think in a posible solution to save the combined information as a primary key. Also you can allow nulls in both columns and make the primary key with the combination; then if you try to insert two times the same IMEI without serial number the database don't allow; but you need some logic to control the update if one IMEI exists and try to add his serial number.